# Crazy about zooming after applying filter to layer

Tags: filter, openlayers, zooming

i know that this question has been asked many times. but i'm really close to give up on doing this zoom after filtering out the layer.

my code is here

```
function filter(){
        OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";
             var filters = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
               type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
               property: "PROVINSI",
               value: document.getElementById("provinsi").value
            });

             var parser = new OpenLayers.Format.Filter.v1_1_0();
             var filterAsXml = parser.write(filters);
             var xml = new OpenLayers.Format.XML();
             var filterAsString = xml.write(filterAsXml);

             wmslayer.params["FILTER"] = filterAsString;
             wmslayer.redraw(true);
             info.vendorParams["CQL_FILTER"] = filter;

            var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
                    "WFS Features",
                    {
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()]
                , projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
                , protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    version: "1.1.0",
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows",
                    featurePrefix: 'rom', //geoserver workspace name
                    featureType: "rom:indonesia", //geoserver Layer Name
                    featureNS: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rom", // Edit Workspace Namespace URI
                }),
                filter: filters
            });
            console.log(wfs);

            map.zoomToExtent(wfs.getDataExtent());

        }
```

the filter function works fine. but i can't zoom in to the filtered layer. i tried using wfs. but when i call map.zoomToExtent(wfs.getDataExtent()); it zoomed to somewhere else.

Comment: Have you played with the projections? If zooming is going somewhere else, it sounds like your map projections are not in sync.

Comment: This has been [cross posted to GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77730/crazy-about-zooming-after-applying-filter-to-layer) where it's also not getting answers - perhaps you could better clarify the question a bit, and decide which site you think is most appropriate for it?

Comment: I have also same issue, but i am using openlayers 4. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284116/how-to-get-extent-of-filtered-wms-layer-and-how-to-zoom-it-with-openlayers-4